# create links with php and htaccess with the same number of slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am trying in PHP to set a converted url in htaccess to get the correct page.
this is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*).html page1.php?caturl=$1&titleurl=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*).html page2.php?caturl=$1&titleurl=$2 [L]
```

and here is the result i should get:

in page1: (get all sub categories of restaurants)

```
domain.com/restaurants/chineese-restaurants.html
```

in page2: (get the restaurant data)

```
domain.com/chineese-restaurans/name-of-restaurant.html
```

now you can see that the 2 links have the same slash "/" numbers...so how can i define that some links get the data from page1 and the others from page2 ?

Comment: You use one page that acts as a router, look into MVC the routing of most MVC systems does exactly what you want.

Comment: @MiDri can i do that in php only ? i never used MVC

Comment: MVC is just an organized way of implementing code, it can be done in php . Look into cakephp or symphony

Answer (score 0):

If all your links for page 2 have a sub category in the name with `-`, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-/]+)/(.+).html page1.php?caturl=$1&titleurl=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+-[^/]+)/(.+).html page2.php?caturl=$1&titleurl=$2 [L]
```

restaurants -> page1
chineese-restaurants -> page2
bla -> page1
bla-bla -> page 2

Comment: Good, but you only have 2 options: 1) add - for all pages 2, or 2) search through a database to see the page.

Comment: Personally, I would use: `domain.com/restaurants/chineese-restaurants` and `domain.com/restaurants/chineese-restaurants/name-of-restaurant`.